# transclude() and ng-repeat not playing nicely

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Trying to transclude a section of HTML which contains ng-repeat statements from within a directive using `transclude()` breaks really badly.  Instead of repeating all the elements one time each, it repeats them all once, then again, then again, repeatedly, for a variable number of times, usually about 17 times.

I annoyingly have to use this rather hack-y way to get the contents to transclude as I can't use the normal template directive and also use the angular-ui-bootstrap $modal function, which requires the template to be added directly to it.

I have narrowed down the problem to before I'm injecting the content into the page, as putting a break-point within the `getBody()` function and typing `transclude()` into the console shows the extra repetition has already happened.

I know the problem isn't with the ng-repeat, as I can copy the contents within the directive call in the main HTML and put it directly after it and the repeat works properly.

Any suggestions of what's going wrong or how to fix it are appreciated.

Below is a cut-down version of the code I'm using to demonstrate:

Main HTML page:

```
<div data-wp-modal="{{'registration.registeredAddresses.allAddressesHead' | translate}} {{entity.type}}"
         data-show="controller.viewModel.openOrganisationAddressModal">
        <table class="table" data-table-name="registeredAddresses">
            <tbody>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']">
                    <td>{{animal}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Directive:

```
// @ngInject
exports.wpModal = function(lpCoreBus, lpCoreUtils, lpWidget, $compile, $modal, $modalStack) {

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            show: "=",
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {

            scope.$watch("show", function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
                    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                        "animation": true,
                         "scope": scope,
                         "controller": "ModalController",
                         "templateUrl": lpCoreUtils.resolvePortalPlaceholders("$(contextPath)/static/launchpad/modules/module-wp-modal/templates/modal.html"),
                         "size": "md"

                    });

                    modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                        // User confirmed the action [performed after doConfirm()]
                        scope.buttonConfirmAction();

                    }, function () {
                        // User cancelled the action [performed after doCancel()]
                        scope.buttonCancelAction();
                    });

                    scope.show = false;
                }

            });

            scope.getBody = function() {

                for (var i = 0; i < transclude().length; i++) {
                    console.log(transclude()[i]);
                    document.querySelector(".modal-body").appendChild(transclude()[i]);
                }
            }


        }
    };
};
```

Modal template:

```
<div data-ng-init="getBody()">

    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>


</div>
```

Output:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <table class="table ng-scope" data-table-name="registeredAddresses">
        <tbody>
            <!-- ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">cat</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">dog</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">bird</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">turtle</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">cat</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">dog</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">bird</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">turtle</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">cat</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">dog</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">bird</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">turtle</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">cat</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">dog</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">bird</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">turtle</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">cat</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">dog</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">bird</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">turtle</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">cat</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">dog</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">bird</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">turtle</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">cat</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">dog</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">bird</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">turtle</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">cat</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">dog</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">bird</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">turtle</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">cat</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">dog</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">bird</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">turtle</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">cat</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">dog</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">bird</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] --><tr data-ng-repeat="animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle']" class="ng-scope">
                <td class="ng-binding">turtle</td>
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: animal in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'turtle'] -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8DD1rgTYOLYHAtsLdm9s?p=preview

Comment: is this angular2 code?

Comment: No, Angular 1.2.29

Comment: what is this then `// @ngInject` ?

Comment: No idea really.  I just know that it works and that the other 12 or so modules (ie directives) I copied to make the basis of this directive from within the project use that syntax.  That's definitely not the problem as the other directives using this syntax don't suffer any adverse effects from it

Comment: can you setup `plunker` with reproducible behavior?

Comment: I've just left the office for the day, but I'll set one up once I get back in the morning

Comment: ok, notify me then using `@` symbol

Comment: @Maximus Plunker added to post

Comment: did you have a chance to look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40169358/2545680)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the problem is that you're calling `transclude()` multiple times which links the same DOM elements multiple times. To see this you can set a breakpoint inside `ngRepeatLink` function

```
return function ngRepeatLink($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
```

in angular.js sources. To avoid that, you can use this code:

```
app.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
          show: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
            var linked = transclude();
            for (var i = 0; i < linked.length; i++) {
              element.append(linked[i]);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Or this is even better:

```
app.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
          show: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
            var linked = transclude();
            element.append(linked);
        }
    };
});
```

Generally, you should not append DOM created by directive outside the directive element, so I appended into directive element.

Comment: Thanks for this, however the problem is that I _do_ have to place the content outside the directive element as it's content to be added to a modal, which is injected as a direct child of body by Angular UI Bootstrap, and the content can't be declared within this modal which doesn't even exist until the bootstraps function is called. Is it possible to do this without resorting to extra templates, which this directive is being made to avoid?

Comment: sure, just do as you did only do not call transclude() multiple times, call it one time as I showed

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help!